# How to use THREE.OBJExporter

Tags: javascript, three.js, export

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367822/exporting-a-three-js-mesh-as-an-obj-or-stl), but if I'm using

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( totalGeom, material );

THREE.OBJExporter.parse( mesh );
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

I read the [example source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/editor/js/Menubar.File.js) (at line 154) but didn't find a solution by myself.. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to create a THREE.OBJExporter object first.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( totalGeom, material );
var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
exporter.parse( mesh );
```